# Как правильно работать с сессиями при создании регистрации на сайте?

Tags: php

Создал простую регистрацию на сайте с помощью [эгото урока](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=347). И возник вопрос. Что нужно вставлять на каждой странице сайта, чтобы незарегистрированный человек не мог попасть на сайт, и чтобы его редиректило на страницу авторизации?

Comment: Первое, что нужно сделать для нормальной работы - добавить в черный список все сайты и курсы Попова. Сделайте это, найдите человеческий материал по вашему вопросу, перепишите всё с нуля и, если тогда что-то останется не понятным - обращайтесь ;)

Comment: @Виктор Павлов, допустим. Хотя всё что отфильтровывается через него, ощущение, что обречено на Г-код. Тогда, если у вас остался один открытый вопрос, то почему бы не [почитать о нем на первоисточнике][1]? Там нет ничего сложного, зато будете знать досконально.


  [1]: http://ua1.php.net/manual/ru/book.session.php

Comment: А ссылочка на первоисточник для меня малополезна. На русском там мало информации. И по сессиям почти ничего нет. А английским я не владею.

Comment: @Виктор Павлов, Относительно грамотно описано [в этой статье][1], НО PDO обязательно


  [1]: http://pyha.ru/articles/php/auth/

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас попробую что-нибудь сделать.

Comment: А как в этом примере, который Вы мне дали, удалить сессию? Чтобы пользователя выкидывало опять на форму регистрации?

Comment: Удаление сессии:

    unset($_SESSION['session_name']);

Comment: без английского в программировании делать нечего. учите хотя-бы технический.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда создаёшь пользователю сессию, в самом начале страницы проверяй, если сессия существует и она не пустая - то давай доступ, иначе выводи сообщение "Необходима регистрация"